# Making question conditionally required in Survey123 form

Tags: arcgis-survey123

When building a survey in Survey123, you can choose whether or not to make a question required but how do you make a question conditionally required?

For example, you have the following questions:

1. Do you like GIS?  (Yes or No?)
2. Why not? (Required if the answer to Question # 1 is "No")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This capability has only recently been made available in Survey123 Connect for ArcGIS.  The version I'm working with is 3.0.142.  If this solution does not work for you, upgrade to the latest version.

When you create a survey, you will need to make sure your field names are all lowercase.  If you have a question that you only want to be required conditionally dependent on the answer to a previous question, ESRI has introduced [Form Expressions](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/xlsformexpressions.htm) for this purpose.

When writing a survey question, you now have three options with regards to the **required** column:

- blank:  Not required
- "yes":  Required
- Form Expression:  Conditionally require using an If Statement.  The If Statement is case sensitive!

To address the example asked in the question, the If Statement would look something like this:

```
if( ${doyoulikegis}='no','yes','')
```

Here's what the form looks like in Excel:
[image: Survey123 Form Construction in Excel]

Here's what the form looks like in action, with each yes and no selected:
[image: Survey123 Form showing Question 2 isn't required when Question 1 = yes]
[image: Survey123 Form showing Question 2 is required when Question 2 = no]

Comment: What if you have a plain text field. I want it to make subsequent questions required if it is blank.

1. What is your name?
2. Why don't you want to share your name?

Comment: @Andy have you tried something like if( ${whatisyourname} is null,'yes','') in the cell for Required for question 2?  The null example is just pseudocode but that is essentially what you want to achieve.  However, it seems like in your example, because you're allowing question 1 to be blank, you'll need to make Required "no" for question 1.