# Making relevant question required in Survey123

Tags: conditional, arcgis-survey123

In my Survey I have several groups of questions where the answer is either satisfactory, unsatisfactory or not applicable. If the answer is unsatisfactory that prompts a four relevant questions.
I would like to make the 4 questions that are prompted by the unsatisfactory answer to be required.

How do I make a question required that is only relevant?

There are over 500 questions I would like to do this for.
I found these two solutions but they don't work for what I am trying to do:

- [Making question conditionally required in Survey123 form?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298634)
- [Make a question required conditionally based on answer to previous question](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/make-a-question-required-conditionally-based-on/m-p/789547#M7938)

Comment: In my experience, you just set "Required" to "Yes" and it just works.  If the questions are not relevant, then they are not displayed, and the "Required" setting is ignored.

Comment: I just assumed it wouldn't be that easy because the questions I wanted required were based off of relevant statements, but I made them required and even if "Unsatisfactory" isn't selected and those questions are not displayed you can still still submit the survey.  If "Unsatisfactory" is selected you cannot submit the survey without answering the relevant questions.

Comment: Does that mean this has solved the issue for you?  (I'm not sure that I fully understood your comment).  I'm going to copy my comment out as an answer, so feel free to accept it it if did solve the issue, or otherwise to comment on the answer if it did not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In similar cases, I simply set "Required" to "yes" and it just works as desired.

If the questions are not "Relevant" then they are not displayed and the "Required" setting of "yes" is ignored.